# Extending Laravel's core component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my project there is a need to extend laravel's generator component. I need it to allow to put in path option so the file would be generated in a location that user would specify. I need this for all generators - from Controllers to Requests etc.

Any hint to where I should start would be much appreciated, thanks

Update:
I found out that I have to modify `Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand` and specifically `getPath` method. How would I override this class?

Basically, all core generators extend this class so I need them to extend my new class somehow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the class those commands extend.

You have 4 options:

1. **GeneratorCommand** uses a **Filesystem** object it gets from container to save files. You can extend **Filesystem** with your own class and overwrite its methods so that they write where you need them too. Be aware that this will impact all other code that uses this **Filesystem** service.
2. Extend all **XYZMakeCommand** classes with your own ones, set a different command name (e.g. my:make-controller) and inside overwrite **getPath()** method, e.g.:

   ```
   class MyControllerMakeCommand extends ControllerMakeCommand {
     protected $name = 'my:make-controller';

     protected function getPath($name) {
       //return the path you need
     }
   }
   ```
3. Live with the default Laravel's path
4. After a command is executed copy generated files to where you want to have it

Comment: This is my exact question, how do I *EXTEND* `XYZMakeCommand` classes. I can't just go to file, and change the `extends` part - it's in the vendor directory. How do I extend it with my own?

Comment: Nope. You'd like to get "ControllerMakeCommand extends MyGeneratorCommand" which is impossible. What you can have is "MyControllerMakeCommand extends ControllerMakeCommand". I'll update the answer in a minute. Anyway, I don't think it's worth the effort and suggest you just copy the generated classes to where you want them.

Comment: I got you point. Thanks, that's the way to go, even better, there in no need to redeclare `protected $name` - it's still possible to use default make:controller. The only issue is that I'll have to get *all* `makeCommands` extend my own classes - the duplications. Thanks, anyway. And no, I have to make them generated there:)